# Detecting and altering the time delta based on daylight savings for GMT (London)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, time

I have the following script snippit:

```
newtime = datetime.datetime.strptime(result_time, "%H:%M")
newtime += datetime.timedelta(hours=5)
result_time = str(newtime.time())[:-3]
```

When daylight savings is in effect it should change the middle line to:

```
newtime += datetime.timedelta(hours=6)
```

However, I'm unable to use `time.localtime()` to do this, it should be checking GMT time in London...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

London is not the same as GMT.  London is either GMT or BST depending on whether daylight saving time is in effect or not.

- If you mean London, use [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) with the `Europe/London` time zone identifier.
- If you mean GMT, then use [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) with the `UTC` time zone identifier.
- If you can run Python 3 and have no need for other time zones, then you can forego pytz and just set `tzinfo` to `timezone.utc` [as directly supplied by Python 3.3](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime.html#timezone-objects).

In neither case would you want to specifically add 5 or 6 hours to your `datetime` object.  If you are trying to compensate for another time zone, such as US Central Time, then you would just use pytz with the appropriate identifier, such as `America/Chicago`.

If for some reason you're attempting to use the local time zone of the machine where the python code is executing, use the [tzlocal](https://github.com/regebro/tzlocal) module, then pass that off to pytz.